# Bluebird promise join is not running in sequence

Tags: bluebird, knex.js

I am using promise with knexjs, but why promise join is not run in sequence, rows got deleted after inserted:

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.join(
    knex('states').del(),
    knex('states').insert([
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Georgia'
    },
    {
       'id': 2,
       'name': 'Tennessee'
    }
   ]);
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join is for promises that run in parallel, not in sequence.  "[For coordinating multiple concurrent discrete promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html)."  Since you want to delete before insert they are not concurrent.

Promises are executed as soon as they are created so I think this is a case for a regular `then`:

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex('states').del()
    .then(function() {
      return knex('states').insert([
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'Georgia'
        },
        {
           'id': 2,
           'name': 'Tennessee'
        }
     ]);
  );
};
```

Of if you like ES6 and having things line up:

```
exports.seed = (knex) => {
  return B.resolve()
    .then(() => knex('states').del())
    .then(() => knex('states').insert([
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Georgia'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Tennessee'
      }
    ]));
}
```